# Подскажите "легкую" back-end платформу web-разработки с минимальным функционалом

Tags: html, cms, php, javascript

Сам я **верстальщик** и продолжаю развиваться в этом направлении. Работаю, обычно, в паре с программистом. Каждый занят своим делом и все по фен-шую :). Однако, встает пара задач - пара рекламных сайтов, крутость которых именно в верстке и программиста привлекать нет необходимости.

**Имеется** ограниченное количество статических HTML-страниц. Максимально-возможная динамика - это редактирование контента на этих страницах. Например, редактирование большого текста "о компании" или возможность добавить нового сотрудника в список (два текстовых поля и фотография). Возможность включить простенький WYSIWYG-редактор для некоторых полей :)

**Хотелось бы** подобрать инструмент для решения подобных задач - простенькую back-end платформу реализующую вот этот вот своего рода CRUD для контента. Возможно какой-то внешний сервис. Хотелось бы чтобы это быстро работало и легко конфигурировалось в ущерб возможностям (что-то обратное CMS-кам типа Drupal, скажем).

**Знаком** с PHP, учу JS. Было бы удобно работать с этими языками :)

Слышал про Deployd, Strawberry, но плохо представляю, что это такое. В общем каша.

**Посоветуйте, пожалуйста :)**

Comment: Нежелание привлекать программиста - это аж три смертных греха:
Гордыня - "я умный, я и сам справлюсь";
Леность - "я не хочу писать ТЗ",
Алчность - "я не хочу делиться бюджетом". ;)

Ну а если серьезно, то задачу можно решить в один экран простого php-кода, т.е. один-дав часа работы для специалиста. Может стоит все-таки оплатить чье-нибудь время?

Comment: Классно написали, есть о чем подумать :). Дело не в бюджете и не в ТЗ, так как задачи, порой, тривиальнейшие, просто "для себя", плюс учащаются. Вот сейчас есть страница-рекламка (одна). На ней текст в несколько параграфов. Хочется дать возможность копирайтеру ее редактировать в более удобном виде, чем теги HTML. Т.е. вопрос авторизации и WYSIWYG.

Comment: А на счет "Я умный, я и сам справлюсь" утверждалось, что обычно в паре как раз и работаю, что все в гармонии. Но это же не означает, что все, конец, от фронтенда ни на шаг. Может что-то несложное можно и самому делать.

Answer (score 4):

Посмотри в сторону [Bolt](http://bolt.cm/).

Comment: Спасибо. Читаю.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, понравилось... я так понял ее не особо можно расширить чем либо...